# numpy.digitize returns values out of range?

Tags: python, statistics, numpy, binning

I am using the following code to digitize an array into 16 bins:

```
numpy.digitize(array, bins=numpy.histogram(array, bins=16)[1])
```

I expect that the output is in the range [1, 16], since there are 16 bins. However, one of the values in the returned array is 17. How can this be explained?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is actually documented behaviour of `numpy.digitize()`:

> Each index `i` returned is such that `bins[i-1] <= x < bins[i]` if
>   `bins` is monotonically increasing, or `bins[i-1] > x >= bins[i]` if
>   `bins` is monotonically decreasing. If values in `x` are beyond the
>   bounds of `bins`, `0` or `len(bins)` is returned as appropriate.

So in your case, `0` and `17` are also valid return values (note that the bin array returned by `numpy.histogram()` has length `17`).  The bins returned by `numpy.histogram()` cover the range `array.min()` to `array.max()`.  The condition given in the docs shows that `array.min()` belongs to the first bin, while `array.max()` lies outside the last bin -- that's why `0` is not in the output, while 17 is.

Comment: Hmm, I do know about the edge case behavior of digitize(). However, since i am using histogram() to create the bins, aren't all values supposed to lie within the bins?

Comment: As I explained in my answer, `array.min()` is supposed to lie in the first bin because it satisfies the `bins[0] <= array.min() < bins[1]` condition, but `array.max()` does not fulfil `bins[15] <= array.max() < bins[16]`, so it's not in the last bin.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. The behavior of the `bins` argument for `numpy.histogram` is different (the last interval is a closed interval), which led to the confusion.

Comment: @sandesh247 I agree with you that making the max value not belong to the histogram seems silly, to say the least. I just hit me when I was computing entropies and things started failing after np.digitize, as there always was 1 outlier no matter number of bins and right=True/False I tried.

Answer (score 2):

`numpy.histogram()` produces an array of the bin *edges*, of which there are `(number of bins)+1`.

Answer (score 2):

In numpy version 1.8.,you have an option to select whether you want numpy.digitize to consider  the interval to be closed or open.
Following is an example (copied from http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html)

x = np.array([1.2, 10.0, 12.4, 15.5, 20.])

bins = np.array([0,5,10,15,20])

np.digitize(x,bins,**right=True**)

array([1, 2, 3, 4, 4])

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a recipe to discretize an array with numpy.
Problem is, np.histogram_bin_edges (and, therefore, np.histogram) and np.digitize are not consistent in how they use bins edges: first 2 always return an extra edge, what ever right mode you use in np.digitize, which always leaves you with one "outlier" category.
What one has to do is (assuming edges appear in ascending order)

```
bin_edges=np.histogram_bin_edges(arr,bins=4) #or any other source
if bin_edges[0] <= arr.min():
 categorized_arr=np.digitize(arr,bins=bin_edges[1:],right=True)
elif bin_edges[-1] >= arr.max():
 categorized_arr=np.digitize(arr,bins=bin_edges[:-1],right=False)
```