# Numpy.digitize() gives more bins than expected when using bin edges from numpy.histogram

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, histogram

My goal is to assign each pixel of an image, in my case an numpy array, the frequency of the bin it falls into. For example, I have a values like `[0.5, 1, 2, 2, 4]` and bin edges like `[0, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5]`. So the frequency for the first bin should be 2, for the second 2, for the third 0 and the fourth 1. So in the result should be `[2, 2, 2, 2, 1]`.

My plan was to first use `numpy.histogram()` to get the frequencies and bin edges and then use `numpy.digitize()` with the bin edges to assign the bin index, in which the pixel falls into, to each pixel. Then I want to use these assigned indices to look in `hist` for the corresponding frequency. But I encountered the problem that `numpy.digitize()` gives me more bins, then there are in `hist` and I cannot tell why.

My code looks like this:

First, I have an image (a numpy array) which looks like this:

```
a_noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, 40000).reshape((200,200))
```

Next, I am taking the histogram it:

```
hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(a_noise, bins='fd')
```

Now I use np.digitize to assign the bin indices to the pixels.

```
a_binidx = np.digitize(a_noise, bin_edges, right=True)
```

As a result I get:

```
hist.shape
```

`(109,)` bins in total, so possible indices range from 0 to 108.

```
bin_edges.shape
```

`(110,)` bin_edges in total, which makes sense to me.
but when I check what bin indices were given, I get as a result:

```
np.unique(a_binidx)
```

`array([  0,   6,   7,  10,  11,  12,  13,  14,  15,  16,  17,  18,  19, 20,  21,  22,  23,  24,  25,  26,  27,  28,  29,  30,  31,  32, 33,  34,  35,  36,  37,  38,  39,  40,  41,  42,  43,  44,  45, 46,  47,  48,  49,  50,  51,  52,  53,  54,  55,  56,  57,  58, 59,  60,  61,  62,  63,  64,  65,  66,  67,  68,  69,  70,  71, 72,  73,  74,  75,  76,  77,  78,  79,  80,  81,  82,  83,  84, 85,  86,  87,  88,  89,  90,  91,  92,  93,  94,  95,  96,  97, 98,  99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109])`

The highest index is 109. The highest index possible for `hist` is 108.

Why do I get 109 instead of 108 indices?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [numpy.digitize returns values out of range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355132/numpy-digitize-returns-values-out-of-range)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using `pandas.cut()`:

```
a_binidx = pd.cut(a_noise.flatten(), bins=bin_edges, labels=np.arange(hist.shape[0]), include_lowest=True)
```

Comment: Exaplanations are highly appreciated. How did this solve the issue? Did it address root cause, or silenced it?

Answer (score 1):

The explanation as to why this happens appears here: [numpy.digitize returns values out of range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355132/numpy-digitize-returns-values-out-of-range?rq=3)
In short, Digitize uses a greater than sign (<) on one side of the bin's edges, and a greater than or equals sign (<=) on the other side, so a point that is equal to the value of the edge of the highest (or lowest if you use right=True) bin, will not be considered to belong to that bin, therefore you get another "bin".
This will happen if there is a point that equals to the highest possible value in the histogram (or lowest, if right=True).

You can decrease the first value in bin_edges by any amount and it should solve the problem, since then the value will not equal the bin's edge.
Then the highest index will still equal hist.shape[0], but the lowest index will be 1 and not 0.

For example:

```js
a_noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, 40000).reshape((200,200))

hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(a_noise, bins='fd')
bin_edges[0] -= 0.1

a_binidx = np.digitize(a_noise, bin_edges, right=True)
print("hist shape:", hist.shape,"bin_edges_shape:", 
bin_edges.shape)
```

I get:

> ('hist shape:', (105,), 'bin_edges_shape:', (106,))

And if I look at the indices we got:

```js
np.unique(a_binidx)
```

The result is:

> array([  1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11,  12,  13,
> 14,  15,  16,  17,  18,  19,  20,  21,  22,  23,  24,  25,  26,
> 27,  28,  29,  30,  31,  32,  33,  34,  35,  36,  37,  38,  39,
> 40,  41,  42,  43,  44,  45,  46,  47,  48,  49,  50,  51,  52,
> 53,  54,  55,  56,  57,  58,  59,  60,  61,  62,  63,  64,  65,
> 66,  67,  68,  69,  70,  71,  72,  73,  74,  75,  76,  77,  78,
> 79,  80,  81,  82,  83,  84,  85,  86,  87,  88,  89,  90,  91,
> 92,  93,  94,  95,  96,  97,  99, 102, 105])

Meaning there are indeed only 105 bins.

Comment: Rather reproduce the issue and demonstrate solving it?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35037575)

Comment: @fravolt, Thank you for your comment, I edited the answer